# Remove Old Commit from source code

Tags: git, extract, history

From what I understand, each git commit stores the changes made to the tracked files since the last commit. Is there a way for you to just delete an old commit out of the source code? For example, if you had a text file

*textfile.txt*

```
Text line one
More text line
```

and you went ahead and committed `git commit -m "Initial Commit"`

You then edit textfile.txt again

*textfile.txt*

```
Text line one
More text line
Even more lines
Just one more line
```

and you went ahead and committed `git commit -m "Added new lines 2"`

You then made on final edit

*textfile.txt*

```
Text line one
More text line
Even more lines
Just one more line
These are the last lines
In this file
```

and commited `git commit -m "Added new lines 3"`

**Is there a way to delete all changes in commit number 2 ("Added new lines 2") so that the file would look like:**

*textfile.txt*

```
Text line one
More text line
These are the last lines
In this file
```

(Notice the removed lines `Even more lines` and `Just one more line` which were changed made in Commit 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with rebase (you don't need an interactive rebase for this):

```
git rebase HEAD --onto HEAD~2
```

Which basically means:

Take all commits from HEAD and further (thus one commit), and apply them onto the parent of the parent (your first commit). So the parent commit (your second commit) is thus skipped.

Before:

```
     HEAD
      |
A--B--C
```

After:

```
A--B--C
 \
  C'
  |
 HEAD
```

Your HEAD now points to `C'` (A copy of the original C), but `C'` has now `A` as parent instead of `B`.

*Edit:*

From your comment on Klas Mellbourn's answer, it seems you want to keep the commit, but want to undo it's changes. That's what [`git revert`](http://jk.gs/git-revert.html) does.

```
git revert HEAD~1
```

Comment: This preserves the 'deleted commit' data, doesn't it?

Comment: The commits are still in the object database, but are elible for garbage collections after a certain period (assuming there is no other branch still pointing to it). For the user standpoint it seems that the commit is gone.

Comment: Any way to preserve the data?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers (By KlasMellbourn and Ikke) erase the commit, "it never happened". Rewriting history like that isn't nice (but sometimes necessary...). You can use `git revert` (just issue it with `--help` for details) to create a new commit undoing the old one.

Comment: +1, this is the correct answer. Rebasing should not be used except in special circumstances.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Rebasing is a kind thing to do. It is an action done to clean up history to make it easier to read for others. In this case removing a commit that was wrong so that others need not read it at all.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn, yes, I do it all the time. But I always get reminded of the people dissapearing from photographs in Stalin's era...

Answer (score 2):

Do an interactive rebase and remove that commit

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

This will show you a list of two commits in an editor. Completely remove the line of the commit that you do not want. Save and close the editor to finish the rebase. The commit and the change will be gone from your visible history (the original commit is still in the repository but will be garbage collected eventually)

Comment: This will delete all history of that commit, won't it? Is there a way to do it so rather than deleting that commit, it commits again without the old commit data?

Comment: If you want that, you basically want to revert commit 2

Comment: Which would be `git revert HEAD~`. That creates a new commit reversing the changes made in the second to last commit. All of these commits will then be visible in your version history.